# How to define dynamic custom Field in ElasticSearch Nest?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

With the following data structure.

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsMobile { get; set; }
}
```

I've created a simple utility function to build a custom Term query. I'm trying to define the fieldExpression using a string. I would like to subtitude "p.Phone.First().PhoneNumber" with a stringExpression parameter instead. Is that possible?

```
private TermQuery BuildTermQuery(string stringExpression, string value)
{
    // Expression<Func<Contact, string>> fieldExpression = p => p.Phone.First().PhoneNumber;
    Expression<Func<Contact, string>> fieldExpression = p => $"{stringExpression}";

    var query = new TermQuery
    {
        Field = new Field(fieldExpression),
        Value = value
    };

    return query;
}
```

If there is other way to accomplish this please let me know. Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using an `Expression<Func<T, TProp>>` lambda expression to access a member of `T` is intended to help with typed access to properties, so passing an expression *string* kinda defeats the purpose :)

It's possible to just pass a string to `Field` constructor, or use the implicit conversion from string to `Field`

```cs
Field f = "my_field";
    
Field f2 = new Field("my_field_2");
```

If you know what casing convention you're using, you could use `nameof()` in conjunction with a property name, then case accordingly. For example, for camel case

```cs
Field f3 = nameof(ElasticContact.Property).ToCamelCase();

public class ElasticContact
{
    public string Property {get;set;}
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToCamelCase(this string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || char.IsLower(s, 0))
            return s;

        var array = s.ToCharArray();
        array[0] = char.ToLowerInvariant(array[0]);
        return new string(array);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For a nested object field, a string can still be passed

```cs
Field f = "phone.phoneNumber";
```

In your example, you could just pass the expression into the method, and avoid strings

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var query = BuildTermQuery<Contact, string>(c => c.Phones.First().PhoneNumber, "123456");
}

private static TermQuery BuildTermQuery<T, TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> fieldExpression, string value)
{
    var query = new TermQuery
    {
        Field = new Field(fieldExpression),
        Value = value
    };

    return query;
}
```

If you *really* want to build an member expression from a string expression, you could reference [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting/) and evaluate the expression string into an expression delegate.

Comment: Russ, thank you for your comment and examples. I have update the question above with example of what I'm trying to do. Please let me know if you have any suggestion on how to specify the Field property for a nested object. Thanks